Vector Commitments vs Accumulators vs Lookups
What is the difference between these primitives. It seems like you can use any of these primitives as a stand in for the other.
To my understanding, accumulators and lookup tables commit to an unordered set of elements, whereas vector commitments are commitments to ordered tuples. Also accumulators support efficient updates whereas lookups don't. Are these the only differences? Because if so, I don't really see why we make a distinction between all of them. What is the difference "in spirit" between these primitives?
